# JSF 1.2 application not getting deployed on websphere 8.5

Tags: jsf, websphere, jsf-1.2, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I am trying to deploy JSF 1.2 application on WAS 8.5 server. But it is throwing below error on deployment.

Note: In the WAS admin, Under JSF implementation use console, I have selected the "Sun Reference Implementation 1.2 " option . But still problem persist.

```
 [12/17/14 15:12:41:222 PST] 00000095 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0}
                             java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
 If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
 <listener>
  <listener-  class>    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:196)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:261)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.destroyFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:293)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:153)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart the application server (not just the app). You should also make sure jsf-api.api and jsf-impl.jar are not in WEB-INF/lib of your app.